# DateTime not inserting into MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, datetime, logout

I am trying to insert Date and Time into a database, it inserts the Date, but not the Time of the DateTime() function

This is the script in question where it is sent to Last

```
$timeZone = date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$now = new DateTime();
$dateTimeNow = $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateTimeNow));
$lastDate = new lastLog();
$lastDate->LogOutDate($_user, $_dt);
```

This is where the user and datetime is being sent to

```
public function LogOutDate($user,$dt){
try{
$_user = $this->db->connection->real_escape_string($user);
$_date = $this->db->connection->real_escape_string($dt);
$query = "UPDATE adminuser SET date=DATETIME('{$_date}') WHERE user='$_user'";
$result = $this->db->connection->query($query);
if(!$result){
throw new Exception($query);
} else {
$this->success = true;
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of your `adminuser` table?

Comment: In order: ID, USER, PASS, DATETIME

Comment: Your column name is `DATETIME`???

Comment: I don't see `datetime` in your query. I see `date`. Add the result of `show create table adminuser` to the question

Comment: `SET date=DATETIME('{$_date}')` I don't get this, you're using `DATETIME` as a function?

Comment: What is the point of `$_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateTimeNow));` when you've already created a formatted date string using `$dateTimeNow = $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: why don't you use `NOW()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html and set the column to a DATETIME "type" and not a function. This question's way too unclear.

Comment: @Matt Barker, I have tried to use the DATE but that didn't work

Comment: The query read:
$query = "UPDATE adminuser SET date=DATETIME('{$_date}') WHERE user='$_user'";
now reads as 
$query = "UPDATE adminuser SET date='$_date' WHERE user='$_user'";

Comment: Thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change following code

```
$query = "UPDATE adminuser SET date=DATETIME('{$_date}') WHERE user='$_user'";
```

to

```
$query = "UPDATE adminuser SET date='$_date' WHERE user='$_user'";
```